# How to only get git commit messages for merges into a particular branch

Tags: git, git-log

In our repo we have 3 primary branches.

[image]

1. `development` developers branch from development, do their work and merge back into development.
2. `UAT` once the client is ready we merge development into UAT
3. `live` once UAT passes we merge UAT into live

I would like a list of all git-log commit messages for merges into the development branch.

I would like to exclude all other merges, e.g. development to some other branch, live to UAT, UAT to dev, dev to UAT.

Currently I have this

```
git log --merges --since="2022-07-27 16:00:00" --grep='Merged\sPR\s\d+:\s' -P --pretty=oneline
```

This will get me all the merge commits

1. since particular date
2. I use grep to filter. All the merges I'm interested in have the text "Merge PR 12345" in the message. This filters out merges from development into some other dev branch (pink with green bar in the image).

How to get rid commit messages for merges from live to UAT to development ?

Comment: What about using `--first-parent`?

Comment: `git log --oneline --first-parent --merges development`

Answer (score 1):

To follow only the leftmost line in your graph (the blue one), add `--first-parent` :

```
git log --oneline --first-parent [other options ...] development
```

Answer (score 0):

The merge message is quite standardize if you don't change it by hand.

For example

```
git log --all --grep="Merge.*into '\?development'\?"
```

Will match commit with

```
Merge branch 'fix/foo' into development
```

and

```
Merge branch 'fix/bar' into 'development'
```

Comment: Relying on merge message content isn't a good general recommendation.